# Get realtime Unix time from internet

Tags: android

I need to show realtime date in my app. Also my program uses Firebase and maybe I can do it through Firebase? I don't want to use APIs with links because then I need to implement json parser libraries with a lot of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/net/SntpClient.java

Sample usage:

```
SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
if (client.requestTime("2.europe.pool.ntp.org")) {
  long now = client.getNtpTime() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() -  client.getNtpTimeReference();
}
```

Comment: Does that need any implementations?

Comment: I tried to compile it and it seems it changed since I used it; better solution exists:
https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android
https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android/wiki/How-to-use-this-library